# How to I write regular expression that split by include token and exclude token

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I am not good using regex.
So I have a question.

I want to split text by specific token.

Token list will be ". ", "? ".

Also I want to exclude specific word in split text.

specific word list will be 'Mr .'.

ex) Mr. Smith bought this. and me too. -> ["Mr. Smith bought this.", "and me too."]

I want to split this text by using (javascript) regex.

How can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I'm sorry about my fault. I will promise do not asking like this question style. So sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a simple regular expression matching the fixed constraints that you have provided. However, I suspect it might not be that usable in the end, especially if you intend to use dynamic split/ignore lists (which would imply some dynamic building of the regex pattern). In any case, I hope the pattern itself can be a good experience for you.

```
var example = "Mr. Smith bought this. and me too.";
var regexp = /((Mr\.)|[^.?]+?)*[.?]/gi;
var result = [];
var captures;
while((captures = regexp.exec(example)) != null) {
    result.push(captures[0]); // trim?
}
console.log(result);
```